# undefined method `update_attributes' while having no update_attributes in Rails 7 with Votable Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran into the undefined method `update_attributes' while having no update_attributes

it showed to me that the following code has issue (Acts As Votable gem)

```
@message.liked_by current_user
```

This is my controller

```
def upvote
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    flash[:notice] = 'Upvoted!'
    if current_user.voted_up_on? @message
      @message.downvote_from current_user
    elsif current_user.voted_down_on? @message
      @message.liked_by current_user
    else
      @message.liked_by current_user
    end
    
  end
```

It happens after the migration of the following code

```
class AddCachedVotesToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :posts do |t|
      t.integer :cached_votes_total, default: 0
      t.integer :cached_votes_score, default: 0
      t.integer :cached_votes_up, default: 0
      t.integer :cached_votes_down, default: 0
      t.integer :cached_weighted_score, default: 0
      t.integer :cached_weighted_total, default: 0
      t.float :cached_weighted_average, default: 0.0
    end

  end
end
```

Also, did the global search and find no update_attributes.

Comment: have you verified this with latest version of `acts_as_votable` gem?

Comment: Exactly!! Sorry for my stupidity. I accidentally used the old version and after the update no more issue! Thank you sir.